# May I install npm locally from the command line? (Not executing a npm install: install npm itself) to use an older version of it for an old project?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

On my computer, I have two *Angular* projects:

1. the first one in *Angular 14*, linked to *Java*
   Its *npm*, *ng* installations are done by the mean of *Maven* plugins, such as
   (I stigmatize the maven plugins call with `groupId:artifactId:goal{configuration}`) :

   ```
   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:install-node-and-npm
      {nodeVersion: ${node.version}, npmVersion: ${npm.version}, 
      workingDirectory: "${basedir}/${contexte-client}"}

   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm{arguments: install}
   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:npm{arguments: run buildProduction}
   ```

   properties assigns `node.version=v18.12.1`, `npm.version=8.19.2` and `workingDirectory=~/dev/Java/comptes-france/metier-et-gestion/AdapterInboundWebEtude/etude`.

   it is working well. Either in production mode, or locally with `ng serve`

---

I have also a *node.js* `18.13.0` installed in my `/user/bin/` to be able to run my `ng serve` commands from the command line.

---

2. a second one is a pure *Angular 12* project, I'm using for learning, following a long video on *Youtube*.

   How did I installed it once, I don't remember. But it worked well by the mean of `ng serve`, util I had to upgrade from *Debian 11* to *12*.

   Then a `ng serve` produced an opaque message about webpack envelope crytpography that was no more allowed, and I thought that `node_modules` weren't accurate anymore. I removed that folder, and did another `ng serve`

   Which failed, with `Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'`, Leading me to run a `npm update`. Which failed too: `bash: npm : command not found`

Was my *npm* inside the `node_modules` folder I have destroyed? I wonder.

I would like to install it again, but in the perimeter of that *Angular 12* project only, with an accorded version for it to run, keeping my other Angular 14 project with its `8.19.2` npm version.

It means that I don't want to see that *Angular 12* npm installed on `/opt` `/user/bin` or somewhere where it would be global, but only locally. Like I believe it was once, to be limited to the strict perimeter of that old project.

Something like `com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin` seems able to do from its `install-node-and-npm` goal with `workingDirectory: "${basedir}/${contexte-client}`

Is it possible?
Or am I doing things the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

If I got right, the NVM is that you need https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Thanks! But eventually, I've changed my mind. `nvm` is a build tool, and can be at the last version for all the computer. I did a simple `sudo apt-get install npm` to gain the `9.2.0` version of it. It didn't change my issue alas: a `ng serve` stills cause an `error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`. That's another research I have now to do, to solve my problem.